# Oracle Hyperion Essbase

Tags: hyperion

A customer has a cube with 13 dimensions and the performance was fine. Now they have added two more dimensions in the existing cube and the performance becomes very very slow. Customer said logically nothing wrong with the two new dimensions they have added. What could be the reason for slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

Slowdown can because of these reasons:

1. Cube is not optimized. Follow hourglass model with most dense dimension at the top then then least dense, least sparse and then maximum sparse at the bottom.
2. Don't use `Dynamic Calc and Store` because it causes fragmentation of database which slows down the performance
3. You can try de-fragmenting the database

I hope this helps.